# .htaccess url rewrite won't work

Tags: html, .htaccess, url

So I am trying to rewrite:

url.com/edit_note.php?noteid=243

to

url.com/n/243

I am using this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule /n/(.*)$ /edit_note.php?noteid=$1
```

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Comment: Try taking out the `/` at the start.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^n/([^/]*)$ /edit_note.php?noteid=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^n/(.*)$ /edit_note.php?noteid=$1  [L]
```